# MariaDB: How do I sort with grouping sets / rollup?

Tags: mariadb, sql-order-by, rollup, grouping-sets

I have s set of data which I want to group with `GROUPING SETS` / `ROLLUP`. There is a fiddle at: https://dbfiddle.uk/XB0nOBWb .

```sql
SELECT initial, data, count(*)
FROM test
GROUP BY ROLLUP(initial,data);
```

Apparently MariaDB doesn’t have a `grouping()` function which gives the grouping level. I would have used that in other DBMSs (such as PostgreSQL) to sort in the right order:

```sql
SELECT initial, data, count(*)
FROM test
GROUP BY initial,data WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY grouping(initial),initial,grouping(data),data;
```

How would I sort this in MariaDB?

I note that in the fiddle (and in my own version) the result is sorted correctly, but I don’t know whether that’s reliable.

Comment: @jjanes My apologies. Wrong DBMS. I’ve been experimenting with a few, and the odd one out is MariaDB.

Comment: If initial can't be null, just test if it is.

Comment: Consider voting for the feature request: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22269

Comment: @ysth Thanks and done. I see that there isn’t a lot of activity on this one.